# How to solve ':mobilertc' error when integrating zoom on react native

Tags: react-native, zoom-sdk

When integrating @zoom/react-native-videosdk then shows this error

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':zoom_react-native-videosdk'.

> Project with path ':mobilertc' could not be found in project ':zoom_react-native-videosdk'.

Please help me to integrate zoom on react native